# Can a mouse button be simulated by the keyboard without enabling numpad mouse emulation?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse, xmodmap, xkb

I'd like to be able to send middle mouse clicks from a keyboard key, for example, the right control key (keycode `105` on my keyboard).

I can remap it using `xmodmap` like so:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Pointer_Button2"
```

But it only seems to work if I have `mousekeys` enabled, by running one of the following:

- Shift-Numlock
- `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/keyboard/mousekeys-enable true`
- `xkbset m && xkbset exp =m`

This remaps the numeric keypad to control the cursor.

Is there some way I can get X to accept mouse events from keyboard keys without converting the numpad to a cursor control?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can :) You have two choise. 
A smart but dirty way is to use `xmodmap -e` to remap all keypad to corrensponding value on keyboard. Like KP9 to 9 (the proccess is the same as you do for mouse button)

The second way is to go `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/mousekeys`, read the file carefully and remove or comment those who are in relation with keypad. (you can comment is c++ way using //)

After edit, reboot the X or your computer and enabling xkb mouse controlbit by `xkbset m` won't affect keypad anymore.

PS: by the way I want to remap a key to mouse button 9 but Pointer_Button9 is not defined :( any comment?